# php check file_exists() out of the third level to the root dir

Tags: php

I struggle with this, any suggestions?

```
  SERVER HTTPDOCS DIR
        /images         <--MAINDOMAIN - domain.com
        /m              <--SUBDOMAIN  (Third level) ROOT DIR  OF m.domain.com

    *FROM m.domain.com/test.php*
```

---

```
$dir="../images";   //Trying to read outside the subdomain root dir

if (is_dir($dir)) {
      $oggetto = @opendir($dir);
      while (false !== ($files = @readdir($oggetto))) {
             if($files != "." && $files != "..") {//print filename}
```

It does not recognize the directory.

Comment: How did you set up the root for the m.domain.com? Can you do a `print getcwd();` from PHP so you'd make sure you are in the folder you think you are?

Comment: print getcwd(); --> /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/m   I need to read into /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/images

Comment: everything works fine from http://www.domain.com/m/test.php :( but not from m.domain.com/test.php

Comment: Hmmm... Do you have the right permissions/owners set on the folders? I would remove the `@` signs to allow failing on errors - that's the way to debug this from here I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the PHP docs for [is_dir()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php), regarding the first passed parameter:

```
Path to the file. If filename is a relative filename, it will be checked relative to the current working directory. If filename is a symbolic or hard link then the link will be resolved and checked. If you have enabled safe mode, or open_basedir further restrictions may apply.
```

In other words, if you specify a relative path, it will be considered relative to the currently executing script, which is why your script works in the first case, but not in the second. Personally I perfer to use full paths when operating on files and directories to make sure I know what I'm pointing at. To poke around a bit and see what I'm talking about try this:

```
<?php
$current_dir = dirname(__FILE__);
$path = realpath( $current_dir . '/../images' );

var_dump( $path );
```

In general, PHP frameworks tend to specify some full paths during their bootstrap, like absolute path to the document root, the application folder, the log folder, etc. and then use those paths whenever specifying a path to a file. This is handy and tends to be very stable because the bootstrap file tends to stay in the same filepath, whereas with the problem you are experiencing, your path resolution breaks when you move the script from folder to folder. I say all this by way of saying you might consider creating a "document root" variable in a header file, for example, include that header file in each of your scripts, and then use that variable when you need to create filepaths.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was the open_basedir!